# My expo app consumes a huge amount of CPU while navigating through different screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I have a React native expo app and It has 4 pages. The app works fine and the average FPS is 58 but when I navigate from one screen to another, CPU usage spikes from (0%-100%) and after like a second it gets back to (0%).

I tried

- Replacing API calls with mocked value
- Checked screen renders and everything is fine

I don't know what can be the problem or how can I investigate more on this.

I use the following react-native, RTK, and navigator

```
    "expo": "~47.0.14",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
```

I am using the [flashlight](https://github.com/bamlab/flashlight) for monitoring preformance